# REST : Handling matrix style and template style parameter with same name in a request

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, django-rest-framework

Consider the following request

```
   GET http://localhost:8080/app/{id}/details;id=some-value-here
```

In the above request, there is one template style parameter named `id` and one matrix type parameter name/value as `id=some-value-here`.

What should be the API behavior while serving such requests?

- Serve request as usual by handling duplicate param keys? because even though parameter keys are same, their paths are different. One is template style another one is matrix style.
- Reject the request saying there is a conflict in parameter names?
- Any HTTP RFC guiding such conflicts resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in RFC.

As per the [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) for URI Template specifically, [section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.1). Variable Expansion says the following (excerpt)

> If a variable appears more than once in an expression or within
> multiple expressions of a URI Template, the value of that variable
> MUST remain static throughout the expansion process (i.e., the
> variable must have the same value for the purpose of calculating each
> expansion).

That means, process the request but keep whatever first value of `id` has encountered throughout the expansion of URI.

For example,

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app/{id}/details;id=some-value-here
```

if `id` were 1, expansion should be

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app/1/details;id=1
```